# A perfect soccer player / journalist etc "Epitome" Vs "Fully-fledged"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-request

I was wondering what would you call a soccer player who is truly well-trained and either physically and mentally is completely ready and in short a player who has all the requirement to be a perfect one in his own kind? Or let's say a journalist who is really well-versed and very intelligent who has all the requirements for his job.

I know the adjective: "[Fully-fledged](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/fully-fledged)", but I'm not quite sure if it is the very adjective that I need.

Please kindly let me know about any possibly better adjective fitting these situations.

### **Added:**

Also, I know another word:
[Epitome:](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/epitome)

I have no idea, which one serves better in my needed meaning and if there is any better term which can encapsulate all me needed concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meanings are rather different.

The expression "fully fledged" comes from birds.  Many birds hatch as blind and featherless chicks.  Later they grow feathers, this is called "fledging". When they have grown all their feathers, and are able to fly, you say that the birds are "fully fledged"

So "fully fledged" metaphorically means "has completed all the training and is now ready for active service.

> After leaving school it takes seven years of study and training to become a fully-fledged midwife.

Epitome (/epit@mi:/) is a word of Greek origin, meaning "The best or most perfect example of something".

> She was the epitome of a midwife: calm, organised, knowledgable, kind but tough.

It seems you want a word that is somewhere between these two meanings. Perhaps simple terms like "excellent" or "superb" would suit your sense better.

The "textbook example" of something matches exactly what a textbook would describe, with no extra complexity and nothing missing. For example the book might say "Granite is a rock with large crystals of equal amounts of quartz, felspar and mica." Some rocks that we still call granite might have small amounts of other minerals or might some small crystals, or not exactly equal amounts. But a rock that exactly fits the simplified description in the text book would be a text book example.

Messi is a fully-fledged football player, but that is rather weak: he has all the skills that a football player needs. But so do lots of other players. Every professional player is "fully fledged".  Messi has been called "The epitome of consistency" for regularly scoring. He hasn't had a bad season. I'm not sure you would call him the epitome of a football player
He is a great player, but not the epitome of a role model off the pitch. I would say "Messi is an outstanding player, perhaps the greatest the world has ever seen."

Comment: Thank you @James K, then I wonder what is the difference between an "epitome" and a "textbook example" while so far the only term which to me meant "The best or most perfect example of something" was "textbook example of something". I was wondering if you could differentiate between these two so that I could find out the answer to this question.

Comment: Also, @James K I am wondering if calling a player like 'Leo Messi' a fully-fledged one sounds natural to you in my needed sense or there is something wrong with it. Please tell me more about it.

Comment: +1 for including the etymology of "fully-fledged" and not just the definition